# Py2app keyflag error CFLAGS

Tags: python, pygame, py2app, setup.py

What I'm trying to do is compile a program I've written in Python 2.7, using pygame, into a standalone app for Mac computers.  I'm working on a PC running Windows 8 with no access to a mac, so tweaking the process has been difficult.

When I run the setup file from the command prompt, I get the "text flood" (similar to what py2exe gave me when it worked to compile the windows version) and the program appears to work.  It creates build and dist folders, but the dist folder has no contents.  When looking at the command prompt output, the last two lines are 
BASE_CFLAGS = cfg['CFLAGS']
Key Error: 'CFLAGS'
This seems to happen when py2app is trying to create the application bundle.

Here is the setup.py file I've gotten to thus far:

```
    """
Script for building the example.

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""
from setuptools import setup

NAME = 'PetCute Slide Puzzle Test'
VERSION = '0'

plist = dict(
    CFBundleIconFile=NAME,
    CFBundleName=NAME,
    CFBundleShortVersionString=VERSION,
    CFBundleGetInfoString=' '.join([NAME, VERSION]),
    CFBundleExecutable=NAME,
    CFBundleIdentifier='Py2App and PyGam test',
)

setup(
    data_files=['Dog1.jpg', 'Dog2.jpg', 'Dog3.jpg', 'Dog4.jpg', 'Dog5.jp', 'Dog6.jpg', 'Dog7.jpg', 'Dog8.jpg', 'Dog9.jpg', 'Dog10.jpg', 'Dog11.jpg', 'Dog12.jpg', 'Dog13.jpg', 'Dog14.jpg', 'Dog15.jpg', 'Dog16.jpg', 'AYearWithoutRain.ttf'],
    app=[
        dict(script="PetCute_slidepuzzle.py", plist=plist),
    ],
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

The data_files lists out the pictures and text file that need to be bundled with the code.  I got to this by adapting the alien.py example.  Please let me know if any more info is needed!

Answer (score 0):

It probably had an error during compilation. I suggest you make sure you have Numpy installed, its needed for py2app to compile Pygame programs.

Comment: Thanks.  I've installed numpy but am still having the same problem.  Do I need to do anything special to point py2app to numpy?

Comment: Im not sure, and as of now i am having issues too. apparently numpy can only handle graphics. I have a question posted on dreamincode, very similar right now, and if i ever find a soloution, i will let you know.